# postgresql valid paramaters and creating a view

Tags: postgresql, parameters

i have a function that takes in the table as a parameter name and i was wondering:

1. how do i create a view to get the correct table

I also have a separate question i have a function with a execute clause inside it i was wondering how would i check if the params corresponded to a table within my database, and if it didn't i want to return a certain value

```
create or replace example(tablename text)
returns bigint 
as $
declare return integer
begin
execute 'select count(*) from' ||tablename|| ';';


... rest of function
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please ask *one* question per question. Both questions seem unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

First part of your question:

```
create or replace example(tablename text) returns bigint as $$
declare
  _retval int;
begin
  execute 'select count(*) from '||tablename into _retval;

... rest of function
```

As for your second question, if by "if the params corresponded to a table within my database" you mean if the function's parameter is the name of an existing table in your database, then you can use `pg_class`:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_class WHERE relname = $1 AND reltype = 'r') THEN
  ...
```